# Model of three mutually exclusive events to be accepted or rejected with confidence .05

Tags: statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

According to a genetic model, three mutually exclusive characteristics A, B, C are present with probabilities:

P(A) = 0.1, P(B) = 0.2, P(C) = 0.7

In a random sample of size 100, A happens to appear 15 times, B 23 times, and C 62 times.
Can we accept this model with confidence level [Alpha] = .05?

I am new to this site.  If there is anything wrong with my question or the way I have asked it, please tell me so that I can fix it.  This is an old qual problem from my department.

My guess is that I need to do some sort of hypothesis test or confidence interval, but I am unable to see how to do this with the three variables.  I would think to do three separate Likelihood Ratio Tests but I do not know how to set this up.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a Chi-Square-Test.

$T=\sum _{i=1}^3 \frac{(t_f-e_f)^2}{t_f}=\frac{(10-15)^2}{10}+\ldots$

$t_f$=theoretical frequency, $e_f$=empirical frequency

df=3-0-1=2

$H_0: \pi_1=0.1,\pi_2=0.2,\pi_3=0.7$

If $T<\chi ^2_{1-\alpha, df}$, then $H_0$ will be not rejected.

greetings,

calculus